# Super Catalan (super ballot) numbers

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, enumerative-combinatorics, catalan-numbers

We refer to [this article by Ira Gessel](https://people.brandeis.edu/%7Egessel/homepage/papers/superballot.pdf). In section 6, page 10, equation (28), the *Super Catalan numbers* are defined as
$$S(m,n)=\frac{(2m)!(2n)!}{m!n!(m+n)!}.$$
On page 12, equation (31), there goes the identity
$$S(m,n)=\sum_{k=0}^m(-1)^k\binom{2n+2k}{n+k}\binom{m}k4^{m-k}. \tag1$$
In [another article by Ira Gessel and Guoce Xin](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL8/Gessel/xin.pdf), the authors introduced the notation
$$T(m,n)=\frac12\frac{(2m)!(2n)!}{m!n!(m+n)!}.$$
On pages 1 and 2, in their attempt at a combinatorial proof they mentioned the two relations
$$T(2,n)=4C_n-C_{n+1} \qquad \text{and} \qquad T(3,n)=16C_n-8C_{n+1}+C_{n+2}$$
where $C_n=\frac1{n+1}\binom{2n}n$ are the *Catalan numbers*. These became my motivation to experiment further and I came up with another version of (1) in the form
$$S(m,n)=\frac12\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}(-1)^jC_{n+j}\binom{m-1}j 4^{m-j}. \tag2$$

> **QUESTION.** It appears that (1) and (2) are very nearly the same, can one be directly transformed to the other without employing $S(m,n)$ as a "negotiator"?

**Remark.** After seeing the above two identities, Gessel showed me a generalization of them both (private communication).

Comment: The generalization referred to in the remark is
 $$S(m,n)=
\sum_{k=0}^{m-l} (-1)^k 2^{2m-2k-2l}\binom{m-l}{k} S(l, n+k) .$$
Identities (1) and (2) are the cases $l=0$ and $l=1$.